# FindStr reads two values but i want to assign first value that is being read

Tags: batch-file

I am running a batch script where i am reading two values from two files and compare those two and perform the action accordingly. The script I am using is:

```
@ECHO OFF

cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Hockeyapp\app"
for /F "tokens=2" %a in ('findstr "versionCode " build.gradle') do set a=%a 
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins"
for /F "tokens=2" %b in ('findstr "versionCode " build.gradle') do set b=%b 
if   "%versioncode1%" == "%versioncode2%" ( 
       ECHO "versionCode is same, hence cannot proceed" 
       cd opt/filenotfound
) ELSE ( 
    ECHO "VERSION CODE CHANGED"
    COPY "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Hockeyapp\app\build.gradle" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\build.gradle" 
)
@ECHO ON
```

My build.gradle file has the term versionCode in two places in it. The first term versionCode has an int value to it and the second term versionCode is used as a reference in the file. I want the script to read the int value assign it to the variable a. But this script is overriding the int value with the string as below.
[image: This is how it reads the two values]

Is there a way to make it read just the int value adn assign it to the variable a.
Thank you.

Comment: Instead of `... do set a=%a`, simply do `... do if not defined a set "a=%a"` (given that `a` is not yet defined, of course, so you might want to place `set "a="` to the top of the script)...

Comment: From the help file for the `FOR` command: **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so the issue i am having here when i run this command " for /F "tokens=2" %a in ('findstr "versionCode " build.gradle') do set a=%a " It is searching for the string versionCode in the file. And the string versionCode exists two times in a file. 1- versionCode = 50 and 2- apkname = $versionCode. The value of a is being set as 50 first which is the desired one but then it reads the second line and overwrites the value a as $versionCode. So i am trying to find a way where it takes the first value i.e 50 and sets it variable a.